# How do I open the next activity by the "Anunciar" button?

Tags: java, android

I created an activity called "RotasActivity", which is nothing but a choice screen with two buttons for the user to choose where to go, this screen comes right after the LoginActivity screen, I made the Intent and startActivity, informing the .class for next activity, but clicking the "Anunciar" button returns you to LoginActivity.

RotasActivity

```
    package com.example.autobuydm;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class RotasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button btnAnuncios, btnAnunciar, btnVoltar;
        private DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_rotas);



            btnAnuncios = findViewById(R.id.btnAnuncios);
            btnAnunciar = findViewById(R.id.btnAnunciar);
            btnVoltar = findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);



            btnAnuncios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent it = new Intent(RotasActivity.this, CatalogoActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });

            btnAnunciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent it = new Intent(RotasActivity.this, CadastroAnuncio.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });

            btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent it = new Intent(RotasActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Destination by clicking the "Anunciar" button (CadastroAnuncio)

```
<pre>

    package com.example.autobuydm;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.autobuydm.R;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

    public class CadastroAnuncio extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText edtMarca, edtModelo, edtPreco;
        private ImageView imgFoto;
        private Button btnTirarFoto, btnCadastrar;
        private Bitmap imgBitmap;
        private final int TIRAR_FOTO = 1;
        private DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        private String CaminhoFoto;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_anuncio);

            db = new DBHelper(this);
            Intent it = getIntent();
            String username = it.getStringExtra("username");
            Cursor cursor = db.SelectByUsernameUsuario(username);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (cursor != null){
                Toast.makeText(this, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "nnnnnnn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            edtMarca = findViewById(R.id.edtMarca);
            edtModelo = findViewById(R.id.edtModelo);
            edtPreco = findViewById(R.id.edtPreco);
            imgFoto = findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
            btnCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);
            btnTirarFoto = findViewById(R.id.btnTirarFoto);



            btnTirarFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (it.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                        /*File arqFoto = null;
                        try{
                            arqFoto = criarArquivoImagem();
                        } catch(IOException e){
                        }
                        if(arqFoto != null){
                            Uri fotUri = (Uri) FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.exemple.android.fileProvider", arqFoto);
                            it.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fotUri);*/
                            startActivityForResult(it, TIRAR_FOTO);
                        //}
                    }
                }
            });
            btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    imgFoto.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] imgBytes = stream.toByteArray();

                    //Por informaçoes de entrada em uma instancia de Anuncio
                    Anuncio anuncio = new Anuncio();
                    anuncio.setMarca(edtMarca.getText().toString());
                    anuncio.setModelo(edtModelo.getText().toString());
                    anuncio.setPreco(Double.parseDouble(edtPreco.getText().toString()));
                    anuncio.setFoto(imgBytes);
                    //Por no bd enviando somente a instancia de Anuncio
                    long sucesso = db.criarAnuncio(anuncio);

                    if(sucesso != 0){
                        Toast.makeText(CadastroAnuncio.this, anuncio.getModelo(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent it = new Intent(CadastroAnuncio.this, AnuncioActivity.class);
                        it.putExtra("modelo", edtModelo.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(it);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(CadastroAnuncio.this, "Falha ao inserir no BD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent it){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode ,resultCode, it);
            if (requestCode == TIRAR_FOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                imgBitmap = (Bitmap) it.getExtras().get("data");

                imgFoto.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
            }
        }

        /*private File criarArquivoImagem() throws IOException {
            String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

            String imgFileName = "PNG_" + time + "_";
            File Diretorio = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File img = File.createTempFile(
                imgFileName,
                ".png",
                Diretorio
            );
            CaminhoFoto = img.getAbsolutePath();
            return img;
        }
        */
    }
```

Comment: Do you have some log on this? What could be happening from your code and what you state, is that somewhere the code crashes and the current activity closes, leaving you in the login activity, if it was not closed before. Could this be happening?
From your code, for me it's not clear why it returns to loginActivity. 
One way to double check this would be to comment your CadastroAnuncio activity code and just implement a simple layout to test the button. I do believe it will open ok.
If it does,  uncomment step by step until you reproduce what you are getting now.

Comment: I think you'd better learn how to debug your code in Android Studio. Check if CadastroAnuncio activity has been started successfully or not. Will it crash somewhere in onCreate() or what...